# How to stop Floating Action Button from being in the foreground?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, floating-action-button

I want to make it so when the .bringToFront() function is called on another View, the FAB will appear behind it. But it looks like the FAB always stays in the foreground.

I created a quick project to illustrate my point.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.samyzarour.floatingbuttontest.MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.testText).bringToFront();
    }
}
```

**Render**

Don't have enough reputation for image, so here's a link if needed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM9ae.png

R.id.testText is placed after the Floating Action Button within the RelativeLayout which already implies that the FAB should appear behind the TextView. I then call .brintToFront() on R.id.testText to bring it to the foreground, yet the FAB stays in the foreground.

Am I doing something wrong here? Please let me know how I can force the FAB to stay behind a View.

Comment: Just call fab.hide()

Comment: Have you tried changing the z-height property on the FAB?  That's what determines which views are in front of or behind others.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys!

Comment: @lionscribe Unfortunately hiding the FAB completely by calling fab.hide() doesn't fit what I'm trying to do. In my use case I want it to re-appear when the View in the foreground slides out of the screen, as if it was in the background all along. Sorry this is my fault, I should of described my specific use-case more thoroughly.

Comment: @rothloup are you sure that z-height is an available property for the FAB? I can seem to find it in the documentation. Is it similar to the z-index in CSS? Please let me know!